# Pie chart series color are black on NodeRed

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-interface, node-red

when I try to draw pie chart on nodered , colors are always black. I m using dashboard-ui node. What is the missing ? or What is best way draw pie chart on nodered ui ?

```
msg.payload=[{
        "series": [ "X", "Y"],
        "colors":['#8b4513','#26138b'],
        "data": [ 77,23],
        "labels": [ "Jan","mon" ]
    }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with this payload, which are stopping it from doing what you would expect:

- the `colors` option is not currently supported as an input, and
- the `data` must be an array of arrays, with the number of inner arrays being the same as the number of series to be shown (so in your case, an array of 1 array of y-values)

This revised payload works for me:

```
    [
        {
            "series": [ "X", "Y" ],
            "data": [
                [ 77, 23 ]
            ],
            "labels": [ "Jan", "mon" ]
        }
    ]
```

The option to specify colors for each series would be a nice feature to add to the `ui_chart` node. For now, you will have to select the colors you want inside the node configuration editor. Please see [the chart node's README](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-dashboard/blob/master/Charts.md) for other examples of valid data inputs.

--
Steve